# Find Whole Duplicated Invoices in SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, string-aggregation

I'm trying to write some SQL to allow me to get result of possible duplicated Invoices that will have the same [same Items, with Same Quantity], That is possible to be Duplicate issued

- Invoice items Average around 300 Item
- Total Invoice To be Revision around 2500 Invoice

The Following is a invoices sample with only 1 items or so, but in real population items average is 300

```
Inv_ID Item_Code Item_Q
A-800   101010  24
A-801   101010  24
A-802   202020  9
A-803   101010  18
A-804   202020  9
A-805   202020  9
A-806   101010  18
```

Hoping The Excepted Result will be

```
A-800, A-801
A-802, A-804, A-805
A-803, A-806
```

But the invoice has around 200 item, and the duplicated invoices has to be has the same items and exact same quantity for these.

## ```
 It's SQL_Server
```

And The Result need to match the whole Invoices item
Like Invoice A has 300 Different Items line with each one Quantity 2
The Results need to be all invoice has the exact same 300 Item with the Exact Quantity.

> The Supplier has issued multiple duplicated invoice to our accounting
> Department by mistakes over 4 years, it was discovered by chance, so
> we need to find out the duplicated invoice to remove it from payment
> schedule.
>
> ## **The issued invoices Need to has the exact different items with exact quantity to be considered duplicated.,,,**

Comment: What's the database engine? PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, Sybase, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS product, so this answer is for [Postgres](http://postgresql.org/).

```
select string_agg(inv_id, ',' order by inv_id) as inv_ids
from the_table
group by item_code, item_q
order by inv_ids;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4b8903b5176b46f939b79c29a8596bf6)

---

Other DBMS products have similar functions to do the aggregation. In Oracle or SQL Server, you would use `listagg()`, in MySQL you would use `group_concat()`. The individual syntax would be slightly different (you have to check the manual), but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you For your Help,, 
when i tested it, the result was each line duplicated result only. 

The Required query Matching is more complex a little , Result Needed here will be illustrated again as ::

**The Result need to match the whole Invoices items ... as Invoice "A-800" has 300 Different Items line with each Item Quantity is "2" ... The Results need to be all invoice has the exact same 300 Item with the Exact Quantity.**

That Mean it has to compare each invoice item against the other invoice line by line, and whole invoices count here is around 2500 invoices

Comment: The Supplier has issued multiple duplicated invoice to our accounting Department by mistakes over 4 years, it was discovered by chance, so we need to find out the duplicated invoice to remove it from payment schedule.
</br>
**The issued invoice Need to has the exact different items with exact quantity to be considered duplicated.,,,**